# Unity aspect ration 80:9

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, aspect-ratio

I have 5 monitors that are connected as a single monitor. Each monitor is full hd and has 1920 on 1080 resolution. In complex they are 9600 on 1080.

So my aspect ratio is 80:9.

When i create level and use standard camera it stretches my textures and meshes on the monitor so it looks ugly. When i use 3 or five cameras the picture is great but i have some cond of distortions on the edges. It looks like the horizontal line is a little bit broken. You can see it on the picture.

I tried a lot of different solutions but it is not working for me.

Is there any advices or solutions that can help me with it?

Thanks

[image: Here how does my monitor looks like]

[image: Here is the problem]

Comment: The distortions are due to the fact that perspective is not linear. So one camera is looking at that edge from the left and the other from the right, and the angle discrepancy leads to that effect. Its the same reason that panoramic shots look "bent."

Comment: Should i use linear rendering except deffered? What do you think?

Comment: No, I mean that you probably can't fix this. Not without a custom camera that can properly interpolate those boundaries. And that goes into math that I am not fluent in.